# Jquery (toggle & collapse) does not loop - Only work once

Tags: jquery, toggle

http://jsfiddle.net/4KUMv/2/

The following script shows a different background depending on the state of the div.

When it is not expanded it shows the "plus (+)" sign, while when is expanded it does not have background image (does not shows anything).

The problem there is that only work once.

(The .mix value makes the Div expands, and the .meta class switch to different background).

Any clue?

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.meta').click(function() {
      $(this).css('background', 'none');
        });     
          $('.mix').click(function(){
            var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');
            var toggle= $(this);
            $('.meta').click(function() {
             $(this).css('background', 'url(images/arrow_down.png) no-repeat scroll 95% 97% transparent');
            });                         
            $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function(){
            });


            $('.meta').click(function() {
      $(this).css('background', 'none');
        });     
          });
        });
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see a 'plus sign' anywhere

Comment: Check out the link again and you will see how it works properly (forgot to set up the online url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks way over complicated. I think what you're looking for is this:

```
$('.mix').click(function() {
    var c = $(this).children();
    c.filter('.meta').toggleClass('background');
    c.filter(':last').toggle(function() {});
});
```

You can then create a CSS class called e.g. `background` that adds the image to the element with class `.meta`.

**Explanation**

As a click on the parent element will always toggle its content, you can attach the event handler to this element `$('.mix').click();`.
The children of this element are always the same, so I select them `var c = $(this).children();`. Now you want to toggle the "+"-sign on a child with the class `meta`. To get this element you can filter the children and toggle the class on the result `c.filter('.meta').toggleClass('background');`. Finally you want to toggle the content. The content is always the last child. So simply filter for that too and apply the function `c.filter(':last').toggle(function() {});`.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/APdKG/)

Comment: Works perfectly! Here is the final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/APdKG/3/ . Anyway I appreciate if you can explain me exactly why you modified the Javascript for another functions where i can't see toggle or collapse and it continue working perfectly. Thanks @insertusernamehere

Comment: I've added a little explanation.

Comment: Awesome... just awesome. Didn't think on do it by this way